# Why does regex detect newline as a valid newline but not \n?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently trying to test out a regex for a project I'm working on, I've found a problem while doing it. (these are C# regexes from `System.Text.RegularExpression`)

The input:

```
11
w
```

Pattern 1:

```
\d{1,}
\w
```

Pattern 2:

```
\d{1,}\n\w
```

in [this](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet) page that I found, it states that \n matches a new line character (and in any other page I could looked at)

so if that's the case, why does pattern 1 match the input but pattern 2 not? shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Well on Windows the line separator is _not_ just `\n`, it's `\r\n`, so maybe this explains your observations.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what Tim Biegeleisen said, "on windows the line separator is not just \n, it's \r\n", with this I changed pattern 2 to `\d{1,}\r\n\w` and everything turned out fine.